# Match multiple words in any order via one regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x

as stated in heading I want regex which will give me results in order based on my 'query'.

```
line='VERSION="OTHER" POWER="LOW" FREQ="OFF" MAXTUN="BLER"'**
```

Example 1:

```
re.findall(r'FREQ="(.*?)"|VERSION="(.*?)"', line, re.MULTILINE)
```

Output is:

```
[('', 'OTHER'), ('OFF', '')]
```

And desired output I prefer is something like:

```
['OFF', 'OTHER']
```

Example 2:

```
re.findall(r'VERSION="(.*?)"|FREQ="(.*?)"', line, re.MULTILINE)
```

Output is the same:

```
[('', 'OTHER'), ('OFF', '')]
```

And desired output I prefer is something like:

```
['OTHER', 'OFF']
```

Any suggestion?

P.S.
Please don't ask me what I want to achieve and tell me that there is maybe better way, only if you have some question regarding this.

Thank you!

Comment: You might use `r'(?:VERSION|FREQ)="(.*?)"'`

Comment: You asked us not to ask, but I just have to: When finding the values for multiple different keys, wouldn't it be very helpful to know _which_ keys those values belong to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may leverage a non-capturing alternation group to match either `VERSION` or `FREQ` (optionally preceded with a word boundary, just check if it meets your requirements):

```
\b(?:VERSION|FREQ)="(.*?)"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/U7j8t1/2)

**Details**

- `\b` - a leading word boundary
- `(?:VERSION|FREQ)` - either `VERSION` or `FREQ`
- `="` - a `="` substring
- `(.*?)` - Group 1 (the actual output of `findall`): any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `"` -  a double quote.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Jv6TXi):

```
import re
line='VERSION="OTHER" POWER="LOW" FREQ="OFF" MAXTUN="BLER"'
print(re.findall(r'\b(?:VERSION|FREQ)="(.*?)"', line))
# => ['OTHER', 'OFF']
```

A better idea, perhaps, is to capture key-value pairs and map them to a dictionary:

```
import re
line = 'VERSION="OTHER" POWER="LOW" FREQ="OFF" MAXTUN="BLER"'
results = re.findall(r'(VERSION|FREQ)="(.*?)"', line)
print(dict(results))
# => {'FREQ': 'OFF', 'VERSION': 'OTHER'}
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/fULAUW).

Comment: Tnx! but look:
print(re.findall(r'\b(?:FREQ|VERSION)="(.*?)"', line)) gives the same 
# => ['OTHER', 'OFF'] 
And I would like now:
# => ['OFF', 'OTHER']

Comment: @Jovan The order is defined by the order of the match appearance in the input string. See [this demo](https://ideone.com/jLLHMg).

Comment: You have right. What would be solution if I want matching by regex order any advice?

Comment: @Jovan I would not even try that, I would capture key-values and map them to a dictionary - see [this demo](https://ideone.com/fULAUW). Else, you will have to run 2 regexes separately.

Comment: You are awesome!! Tnx!

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no way to match in the order you want using regex: you could execute the part before | first, and then the part after |. Or order the result afterwards.