# Regex to replace multiple occurrences in list of words

Tags: python, regex

A list of items, some of them contain specifications, which the format is "number + space + unit".

I want to remove the specifications, so only item names left.

```
import re

list_words = ["Banana 12 Units",
"Banana 5 Units",
"Green Apple",
"Red Date 2 Boxes",
"Red Date 4 Boxes",
"Mango 3 Packs",
"Mango 16 Packs"]

for w in list_words:
    w = re.sub('(\d+ )Units', '', w)
    w = re.sub('(\d+ )Boxes', '', w)
    w = re.sub('(\d+ )Packs', '', w)
    print w

#Banana
#Banana
#Green Apple
#Red Date
#Red Date
#Mango
#Mango
```

It works ok, but I want to learn a better way.

Comment: Use a non-capturing group with alternation operators inside: `r'\d+\s+(?:Units|Boxes|Packs)`. To match any word just use `\w+` instead of `(?:Units|Boxes|Packs)`.

Comment: You can make the replacement more generic by replacing this `\s*\d+\D*$` with empty string, assuming digits only occurs once

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, thank you! would you like to make it as an answer so that I can choose to close this question?

Comment: @MarkK  I have [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47262730/3832970) a next to identical question, no need to repeat.

Comment: Not my downvote, BTW.

Comment: Upvoted this one - I thought it was. :)